# How to save id when I use Autocomplete Text View in Nativescript

Tags: angular, autocomplete, nativescript

I have e problem in my code.

I'm using Autocomplete Text View.

In first, I get all country from API, simple JSON with ID, name etc.

```
 {
            "country_id": 249,
            "name": "Aland Islands",
            "short_name": "AX",
            "company_id": "11E76234942280FBB13FFA163ECD2069"
        },
```

I show correct data name in Autocomplete. I want to save data ID.

In Html:

```
<StackLayout backgroundColor="#66cdaa" padding="5">
    <Label text="Select country"></Label>
    <RadAutoCompleteTextView [items]="dataItems">
        <SuggestionView tkAutoCompleteSuggestionView>
            <ng-template tkSuggestionItemTemplate let-item="item">
                <StackLayout orientation="vertical" padding="10">
                    <Label [text]="item.text"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </ng-template>
        </SuggestionView>
    </RadAutoCompleteTextView>
    <Label text=""></Label>
    <Button class="my-button" text="Sign Up" (tap)="register()"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

I create a [DEMO](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=Dee1nl)

How to register ID. For example I select Aland Islands, when I register I want to register country_id: 249.

Comment: Loop through the countries collection, find the object matching the selected name and access it's id.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do it. The best way requires a couple of steps but gives you the cleanest code and you are able to scale it for the future, easy debugging, etc

For everything to work, update the package "nativescript-ui-autocomplet" to the current latest version (5.1.0)

1. Create a custom token model
2. Use the onLoadedModel event to register a loadSuggestionsAsync callback function
3. Use the didAutoComplete event to get the selected item

Example of a custom token model:

```
export class CountryToken extends TokenModel {
    country_id: number;
    name: string;
    short_name: string;
    company_id: string;
    constructor(country_id: number, name: string, short_name: string, company_id: string) {
        super(name, null);
        this.country_id = country_id;
        this.name = name;
        this.short_name = short_name;
        this.company_id = company_id;
    }

    toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Bind to the event (loaded)="onLoadedCountry($event)"

Don't forget to amend the method to your needs by using your own service or the way you pull the data from the source.

```
onLoadedCountry($event) {
    const radAutoComplete = <RadAutoCompleteTextView>$event.object;

    radAutoComplete.loadSuggestionsAsync = (text) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.addressService.searchLocation(text).subscribe(
                (data) => {
                    const items: Array<CountryToken> = [];
                    data.forEach((item) => {
                        items.push(new CountryToken(item.country_id, item.name, item.short_name, item.company_id));
                    });
                    resolve(items);

                },
                (error) => {
                    console.log("error .");
                    console.log(error);
                }
            );
        });
    };
}
```

Bind to the other event to get the result (didAutoComplete)="onCountrySelected($event)"

```
onCountrySelected($event: AutoCompleteEventData) {
    const token = <CountryToken>$event.token;
    console.log(token.country_id)
}
```

Use them in the HTML file similar to:

```
RadAutoCompleteTextView (didAutoComplete)="onCountrySelected($event)" (loaded)="onLoadedCountry($event)" completionMode="Contains" suggestMode="Suggest" displayMode="Plain">
    <SuggestionView tkAutoCompleteSuggestionView suggestionViewHeight="300">
        <ng-template tkSuggestionItemTemplate let-item="item">
            <StackLayout orientation="vertical" padding="10">
                <Label [text]="item.name"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </ng-template>
    </SuggestionView>
</RadAutoCompleteTextView>
```

For more details see this closed github issue [[RadAutoCompleteTextView] Allow passing customized Token Model](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/65)

Comment: Hey Culita, I noticed that you are active lately in the nativescript tag in StackOverflow. Just wanted to say thanks for helping to the community. If you feel like, you can grab [a pack of stickers](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-first-time-contribution-contest-continued-and-extended) from the team.

Comment: thanks, @anthares  my laptop it's waiting for them :P